# Does this mean that $x = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{a_i}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This feels very basic, but I'm wondering if there is anything subtle here.

Assume $x, a_i, b_i\geq 0$. Let's say I can have that:

$$x = b_1$$
$$b_i = a_i + b_{i+1}$$

Then, I can definitely say that:

$$x = b_1 = a_1 + b_2 = a_1 + a_2 + b_3 = a_1 + a_2 +a_3 +b_4 = \cdots$$

However, can I then conclude that:

$$x = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{a_i}$$

This seems right to me, but wondering (a) if this is always true or is there something subtle I need to worry about; and (b) if so, how to prove this?

Comment: You are assuming $b_i \rightarrow 0$. Take for example $a_i=0 \ \forall i, b_i=1 \forall \ i$.

Comment: @FOE right, good point. I think I see the additional condition I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(b_i)$ is a non-increasing sequence of positive numbers, so it tends to a limit $B$. Now what you *can* say is
$$x=B+\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$$

But there is no guarantee that $B$ is non-zero, as FOE's counterexample shows.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. So, just to double check, if $b_i \to 0$, then I can draw the conclusion above?

Comment: Yes, it works on both directions. If the sum si equal to $x$ the sequence of $b$ must converge to zero